# Doctrine 2: Transaction does not work

Tags: php, nginx, doctrine-orm

Code handled by my request (just testing purpose):

```
$em->beginTransaction();
try {
    $repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
    /** @var User $entity */
    $entity = $repository->findOneBy(['user' => 1]);
    $em->lock($entity, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    // $em->refresh($entity); Would solve the problem. See edit at bottom.
    $entity->increase(1); // just an integer field will be increased

    sleep(2);

    $em->persist($entity);

    $em->flush();
    $em->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $em->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

When I fire up two requests (handled by different Nginx children) following happens:

1. Before requests: Number is 30
2. Request 1 is fired
3. Request 2 is fired
4. Request 1 finished. Number is 31
5. Request 2 finished. Number is **31**

I expect **32** after finishing of the second request since there are write locks inside of a transaction set. Why does that not work?

Edit: I have to add `$em->refresh($entity)` to get it work. But I wonder if I have to do that manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution with doing `$em->refresh($entity)` is the way to do it. I asked the Doctrine 2 developer.